# Requiring '.js' Extension for Proper Import/Export Functionality in NodeJS Module Type

Tags: node.js, module

I experience the problem that when I want to use export/import in my NodeJS application I get the error: 'Cannot find module'.

I expected this to work:
import Test from "./modules/test";

But for it to work it must:
import Test from "./modules/test.js";

As folder structure I have:

```
package.json
    src ->
        modules ->
           test.js
        server.js
```

My package.json:

```
{
     "type": "module",
     "name": "test",
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "description": "",
     "main": "index.js",
     "scripts": {
         "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
         "start": "node src/server.js"
     },
     "keywords": [],
     "author": "",
     "license": "ISC"
}
```

Error I get:

```
node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:255
    throw new ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND(
          ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\pasca\Desktop\test\src\modules\test' imported from C:\Users\pasca\Desktop\test\src\server.js
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:255:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:908:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1121:11)
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:396:12)
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:365:25)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:240:38)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:85:39)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:84:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  url: 'file:///C:/Users/pasca/Desktop/test/src/modules/test'
}

Node.js v20.10.0
```

If anyone knows of this problem, I'm very curious to know what the problem is!